# Hosting WCF Services in Multiple Windows Services in the Same Process

Tags: .net, wcf, appdomain, self-hosting

I am building a windows service to host a WCF service, and I am using :

```
var ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
            { new Service_1_Host() };
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

My question is:

if I have a second service with its host, and I added to the array in the above code, like the following:

```
var ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new Service_1_Host(), 
                                        new Service_2_Host() };
ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
```

does the second host run with its own app domain, or there is some configuration I have to do to make the two hosts run it separate app domain each?

Answer (score 3):

You approaching this all wrong.... you need to keep apart:

- the Windows NT Service (derived from `ServiceBase`) which is merely here to be running around the clock
- the actual WCF service hosts (derived from `ServiceHost`) which provide the real WCF service interfaces.

Basically, what you need to do is this:

- in your NT Service (`ServiceBase`) there's an `OnStart` event - inside that event, you need to create and open your WCF `ServiceHost` instances - one per WCF service (implementation) class
- in that NT Service (`ServiceBase`) there's an `OnStop` event, inside of which you should close your WCF service hosts

Some your code would look roughly something like:

```
using System;
using System.ServiceModel;

namespace YourNameSpace
{
    public class WcfHostService : ServiceBase
    {
        private ServiceHost _serviceHost1 = null;
        private ServiceHost _serviceHost2 = null;

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            // instantiate new ServiceHost instances 
            if (_serviceHost1 == null)
            {
                _serviceHost1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourService1));
            }

            if (_serviceHost2 == null)
            {
                _serviceHost2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(YourService2));
            }

            // open service hosts
            _serviceHost1.Open();
            _serviceHost2.Open();
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            if (_serviceHost1.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                _serviceHost1.Close();
            }

            if (_serviceHost2.State != CommunicationState.Closed)
            {
                _serviceHost2.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

and then in your NT Service main app, you would have:

```
var servicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] { new WcfHostService() };
ServiceBase.Run(servicesToRun);
```

That's all, really!

Answer (score 2):

Notice that this is an array of `ServiceBase`, not of `HostsBase` or something. You are simply starting up multiple Windows Services. This has nothing to do with WCF or even with AppDomains.